# Blazor get selected text from textarea and make it bold/italic/hyperlink

Tags: textarea, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Is there any way to get selected text from textarea and make it bold/italic/hyperlink in Blazor WebAssembly?
Or it should be done using javascript?

Comment: Should be done via javascript.

Comment: Not even with JavaScript - `textarea` doesn't allow HTML content. The rich web editors you may use in forums don't use `textarea`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have HTML content in a `textarea` element which means you can't do what you want even with JavaScript. The rich editors you see in forums and sites use different elements and quite a bit of JavaScript.

You'll have to use such a text editor, either directly through JavaScript or a wrapper like [Blazored TextEditor](https://github.com/Blazored/TextEditor) which works on top of [Quil.js](https://quilljs.com/). All commercial component vendors have their own rich text editor components as well.

Check the [Awesome Blazor](https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor) page for a list of components, component bundles and tutorials.